# LitElement use of template with binding

Tags: lit-element

I was wondering how to make LitElement work similar to Polymer 2/3 templatizer, i.e. grab template from light dom (childElement), templetize it and stamp it. It used to be possible and was used in elements such as dom-repeat etc, however with LitElement and its internal working with tagged string templates I do not see how to make an element accept a template to use internally, but the template being provided by the user of the shipped element (i.e. same as dom-repeat used to allow that).

I am aware of how to do it when writing the code, I just want to allow the consumer of my custom element to be able to provide the template and its bindings to work and not to subclass my element but instead use the simpler and already well known html composition from polymer2/3

Comment: Would props not work?

Comment: How would I pass an html written template into a property? The way 'dom-repeat' works in Polymer is preferred: let the user specify the template (and the data bindings) from html and use that to stamp out items. The 'idiomatic' way to do this in 'react like' (and assuming - in LitElement as well) would be to extend the base repeater element and override the 'item' template I guess... I just need a confirmation if this is what is expected to be done in lit*

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this with just lit-html, as everything is built on JS template strings. You might be interested in [Stampino](https://github.com/justinfagnani/stampino), which is built on lit-html. It's in pre-release as of this writing.

```html
<template id="root">
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  <ul>
    <template type="repeat" repeat="{{ items }}">
      <li>{{ toUpperCase(item) }}</li>
    </template>
  </ul>
</template>

<output></output>

<script type="module">
  import { render } from 'stampino';
  render(
    document.getElementById('root'),
    document.querySelector('output'),
    {
      letters: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      title: 'Hello World',
      toUpperCase(string) {
        return string.toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  );
</script>
```

That would render the following to the `<output>` element:

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

If you're already writing HTML inside a lit-html template, however, a pattern that may fit your use is so-called "render props". Here's a simplified example:

```js
html`
  <list-renderer
      .items="${[...items]}"
      .template="${item => html`
         <list-item>${item}</list-item>
  `}"></list-renderer>
`;
```

in which,

```js
class ListRenderer extends LitHTML {
  render() {
    return html`
      <ul>
        ${this.items.map(item => this.template(item))}
      </ul>
    `;
  }
}
```